# How to programmatically drop a pegman on click of a point in the map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, street-address

How will I be able to drop the pegman programmatically on a point on a map. I have a "click" event of the map. I need to drop the pegman on the coordinates where it was clicked.

Comment: Just a quick thought. Could you set the location of the panorama to that click position. If the two are tied together then that should place the pegman on the map.

Comment: @Rafe Yes i have set the location of panorma to that click position but it is not placing the pegman on the map.

Comment: Have you tied the two together with map.setStreetView(panorama); Showing your code might help

Comment: Hey i got it. I removed streetViewControl: false and then it was working... Your thought gave me an idea. Thank you :D

Comment: I had that same problem. The map I am working on I hide the controls and show them on mouseover. I had to show streetViewControl, move the map and then hide it again.

Comment: In my condition. I had to remove the pegman from the map and draw an icon similar to pegman on the map on click of a location. Please Post your answer so that i will accept...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the pegman to appear on a map, you need to enable the streetview controller.

It can be disabled again after if you wish.

Check comments on original post for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Pegman can be placed by application on a map, when the map and panorama containers are separated and panorama is associated to the map.

eg.:

HTML

```
    <div id="mapContainer"></div>
    <div id="svpContainer"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
    var mapElement = document.getElementById('mapContainer');
    var svpElement = document.getElementById('svpContainer');

    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, {...});

    var svp = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(svpElement, {
       position: {lat: svpLat, lng: svpLng},
       visible: true,
       ...
    });

    map.setStreetView(svp);
```

The trick is, that svpContainer can be hidden as HTML Element by 
CSS

```
    #svpContainer {
        display: none;
        ...
    }
```

or

JavaScript

```
    document.svpElement.hidden=true
```

or whatever (instead of svp being switched off from within itself [funcionality of svp option *enableCloseButton: true*] nor using programmically svp option *visible:true/false*) !

Svp option "visible" is the clue. It must be "true", to keep Pegman on the map.

In result the Pegman is on the map in the choosen by you place:

```
    svp.setPosition({lat: ...,lng: ...});
```

Go mad :D